# Tensorflow TFRecords "Data types don't match" problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

trying to read frames for TFRcord file and in the last frame I get:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Key: frame2.  Data types don't match. Data >type: float but expected type: string

the code is:

```
def parse_function(proto):
    # define your tfrecord again. Remember that you saved your image as a string.
    keys_to_features = {'class': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

    for i in range(FRAMSE_PER_VIDEO-1):
        keys_to_features['frame'+str(i)] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string)
    print(keys_to_features)

    # Load one example
    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_single_example(proto, keys_to_features)
    print(parsed_features)

    #reading first frame and starting tensor

    frame = (parsed_features['frame' + str(0)])
    frame = tf.io.decode_raw(parsed_features['frame' + str(0)], tf.float32)
    frame = tf.reshape(frame, [WIDTH1, WIDTH1, 3])
    video = tf.expand_dims(frame,0)

    # Turn  saved image string into an array

    for i in range(FRAMSE_PER_VIDEO-2):
        frame = (parsed_features['frame' + str(i+1)])
        print(frame)
        frame = tf.io.decode_raw(frame, tf.float32)
        frame = tf.reshape(frame, [WIDTH1, WIDTH1, 3])
        frame = tf.expand_dims(frame,0)
        video = tf.concat([video,frame],0)

    return  video, parsed_features["class"]
```

When I write the TFRecord, I write all frames in the same method so there shouldn't be a difference

what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same issue